# Change child views to fit parent's width when added dynamically

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I have a custom view which I add child views to dynamically.

When each child is added, I need to recalculate the size of the views so they can fit the parent's width

For example:
If I have a TextView:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="8dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:textColor="#666666"
android:visibility="visible"/>
```

If I add three of these to a horizontal LinearLayout within the xml it correctly sizes the three views so the total widths match the parent.

But I want to inflate them one at a time and add them so can reuse elsewhere in the code if we want a different number of TextViews in a layout.

When I do this, the total width is less than its parent, and I can't get the views to resize when a new one is added.

Here's where I inflate the view:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.segmented_control, this); 
TextView item = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.segmented_control_item, null);
```

Comment: Show us the code where you inflate the Views. Also make sure to pass the parent View to the LayoutInflater when you create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width to `match_parent`, i think you need to keep the `weight`. Pass the parent layout to the inflater.

```
layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.segmented_control, this); 
TextView item = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.segmented_control_item, layout, false);
layout.addChild(item);
```

I'm not sure if that works right away, you might need to experiment a little with the layout paramters.

Comment: Thanks so much, changing the width to match_parent, keeping the weight and passing the parent layout to the inflator worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your TextView layout width to fill_parent and remove the weight. I think that it should work.

Comment: Removing the weight caused the last TextView to span the whole width so  the other TextViews could not be seen. Solution above worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks for the reply :)